# Not able to optimize a SQL Query. Taking huge cost. Oracle Apps

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization, oracle10g, po

This is a query which I have to use as part of extracting Receipts based on certain conditions from Oracle 11i as a part of Conversion.

--> One important check is to check for invoices on hold. I just need to pull the details wherein the invoices are on hold. And the condition for checking is

In AP_HOLDS_ALL table -- 1) the invoice should exist
                         2) release lookup code should be NULL 
                         3) status flag should be S or NULL and 
                         4) there should not exist any line in AP_HOLDS_ALL table with same invoice ID with release lookup code as not null.

I have tried and added the below criteria in last of the following query, but it fetches the rows very very slow (100 000 records in a day).

How to improve the performance?

```
    select * -- multiple Columns
    from rcv_shipment_headers  rsh,
   rcv_shipment_lines    rsl,
   rcv_transactions      rt,
   hr_operating_units    hou,
   po_headers_all        poh,
   po_lines_all          pol,
   po_line_locations_all pll,
   po_distributions_all  pda,
   po_vendors            pv,
   po_vendor_sites_all   pvs
    where 1 = 1
and rsh.shipment_header_id = rsl.shipment_header_id
and rsh.shipment_header_id = rt.shipment_header_id
and rsl.shipment_line_id = rt.shipment_line_id
and rt.po_header_id = poh.po_header_id
and rt.po_line_id = pol.po_line_id
and rt.po_line_location_id = pll.line_location_id
and rt.po_distribution_id = pda.po_distribution_id
and poh.po_header_id = pol.po_header_id
and pol.po_line_id = pll.po_line_id
and pll.line_location_id = pda.line_location_id
and poh.org_id = hou.organization_id
and poh.type_lookup_code = 'STANDARD'
and poh.authorization_status = 'APPROVED'
and poh.approved_flag = 'Y'
and rsh.ship_to_org_id = pll.ship_to_organization_id
and rt.organization_id = pll.ship_to_organization_id
and pol.org_id = hou.organization_id
and pll.org_id = hou.organization_id
and pda.org_id = hou.organization_id
and hou.date_to is null
and (rt.transaction_type = 'DELIVER' or rt.transaction_type = 'RECEIVE')
and rt.vendor_site_id = pvs.vendor_site_id
and rt.vendor_id = pv.vendor_id
and pv.vendor_id = pvs.vendor_id
and (nvl(pda.quantity_ordered, 0) - nvl(pda.quantity_cancelled, 0)) > 0
and nvl(pda.quantity_delivered, 0) > 0
and nvl(pda.quantity_billed, 0) > 0
and nvl(rsl.quantity_received, 0) > 0
and ((nvl(pda.quantity_delivered, 0) = nvl(pda.quantity_billed, 0)) or
    (nvl(pda.quantity_delivered, 0) > nvl(pda.quantity_billed, 0)) or
   (nvl(pda.quantity_delivered, 0) < nvl(pda.quantity_billed, 0)))

and exists
 (select aida.po_distribution_id
      from ap_invoices_all aia, ap_invoice_distributions_all aida
     where aia.cancelled_date is null
       and aida.po_distribution_id = pda.po_distribution_id
       and exists
     (select c.invoice_id
              from ap_holds_all c
             where c.release_lookup_code is null
               and c.invoice_id = aia.invoice_id
               and c.org_id = nvl(p_leg_operating_unit, c.org_id)
               and (c.status_flag = 'S' or c.status_flag is null)
               and not exists
             (select 1
                      from ap_holds_all d
                     where d.invoice_id = c.invoice_id
                       and d.org_id = nvl(p_leg_operating_unit, d.org_id)
                       and d.release_lookup_code is not null))
         and aia.org_id = nvl(p_leg_operating_unit, aia.org_id)
         and aia.invoice_id = aida.invoice_id)
   and poh.org_id = nvl(p_leg_operating_unit, poh.org_id)
```

- p_leg_operating_unit is a parameter which is having NULL value as I am trying to get the values for all the OU's

** last exists is causing the issue.

Comment: Can you try parallel execution ?
SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(4) */ * from ...

Comment: Thanks..Let me try that.. I ll post the result.

Comment: I tried with parallel but it does not work. Indeed it increased the cost of the query

Answer (score -3):

Try with the following , may solve your issue :

1. /*+ parallel(4) */ --hint. If doesnt work , then try with
   parallel(8)/parallel(16).
2. Reorder the joins . Join the tables based on the least number of rows returned. FOr example Table A,B,C . Join a & b returns 100
   rows, but B&c returns 20 rows. then First join B & C table and join
   with A.
3. Use /*+ Index * hint if optimizer doesn't access indexes.

Comment: Thanks Sathish for your help but I tried reorganizing, using Index or parallel. It does not speed up the query.